# Access file on another computer using SQR

Tags: file, external, sqr

I want to import pictures from another computer on our network than where SQR is running.  I am wondering how best to specify the path so that the file can be opened.  I have had our user name that runs when running and SQR added to the other computer's user list with permissions to read.  The SQR runs on Linux and is accessing another Linux box.
I have tried:

```
let $path = '//server/somewhere/file.jpg'
let $path = '\\server\somewhere\file.jpg'
```

and others, but when I issue:

```
let $cmd = 'ls ' || $path
call system using $cmd #result
```

## result is always 2 - can't find file/directory.

Is anyone else doing this successfully?

Comment: Try this command from the Linux command prompt and make sure it works.  If it does, hardcode the complete command and in SQR, run it with: call system using 'ls \\server...' #results